# What triggered the acceleration in human advancement?

Tags: technology, prehistory

If you look back 100,000+ years humans were living in caves. They lived in caves for millennia. They used the same stone tools for millennia. They painted the same wall paintings for millennia.

The Stone Age was over 3 million years ago. And then nothing for millions of years and then things started to accelerate. Suddenly the Bronze Age, the Iron Age, and things accelerated from there too.

And now we see changes every year or less.

What was the trigger for these advances? Or (conversely) what was the reason for the long (tens/hundreds of lifetimes) periods of stagnation?

I know it’s theoretical as we can’t know for certain but are there any theories as to why it is this way?

Comment: Hi. Does the Wikipedia article on the [Neolithic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neolithic) answer your question?

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help] and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: ***They used the same computers for millennia...*** (You might strongly disagree, of course, but someone from the far future, possessing technology we cannot even begin to imagine, let alone comprehend, might not be able to perceive any particularly meaningful difference between the furniture-sized calculators of the 1940's, and the latest, state of the art tablet, laptop, or cellphone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at human history on that time scale, two key turning points stand out. One is the Neolithic Revolution and the other is the Industrial Revolution. In both cases, specific technological breakthroughs (especially in agriculture but also in other fields) meant two things. First, they allowed fewer person-hours to be spent per unit of goods produced. Second, they allowed the overall size of the human population to increase beyond previous limits. Those two dynamics taken together, productivity growth and population growth, supported one another and produced cycles of exponential change.

Multiple [Neolithic Revolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neolithic_Revolution) took place independently in different regions. They involved hunter-gatherers settling down and domesticating plants and animals to become full-time agriculturalists. Once this change was underway, other developments became possible like metalworking, writing and statecraft. A Bronze Age followed in many (but not all) cases of Neolithic Revolution across Eurasia, Africa and the Americas.

The [Industrial Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Revolution) was initially centered in England but diffused globally to such an extent that we can think of it as a single global event unfolding over a few centuries. The key developments in agriculture here were not new domestications so much as other kinds of technical change like greater and more effective use of fertilizers, more advanced breeding and husbandry, etc. This was more or less simultaneous with the harnessing of coal and later petroleum for industrial production. Unprecedented scientific understandings of physical and biological laws have been an important part of all of this.

What caused the relative stagnation before and in between these two revolutions? At the risk of over-simplification we can think of this in terms of the ecological "[carrying capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrying_capacity)" of human populations. Given a certain set of technologies, a society will reach a certain limit beyond which it cannot grow. If population begins to surpass that limit, problems like famine and disease will reverse the trend. The result is a kind of relative stability. These two revolutions broke through the previous ceilings of population growth and allowed unprecedented kinds of societies to emerge. Normal incremental improvements are not enough to do that.

If you'd like to understand all of this in more depth, I strongly recommend [the book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Maps_of_Time.html?id=Bs_sLdKGS5gC) *Maps of Time: An Introduction to Big History* by David Christian.

Comment: That’s excellent. Thanks very much and it makes sense about the equilibrium reached by population size / technology etc... I’ll definitely have a read of the book you recommended. Thanks very much. 